# interprocess communication in linux design

Tags: linux, perl, c++11

I am running linux . I have two processes lets say side-process and main-process. 
side-process interacts with driver and gets SIGIO from driver and populates information from the driver.

Process B needs to get information from process side-process whenever side-process gets SIGIO and side-process then generates events and decides what to do with the event.  main-process is kind of central process and it interacts with other dozens of processes. How should be the communication between  side-process and main-process? how to notify main-process When I get SIGIO at side-process.

Comment: Perhaps a [message queue](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html)? Perhaps [local sockets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html)? Perhaps named [pipes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)? It all depends on your requirements really. Experiment with all these, and other methods like shared memory, normal network sockets, and even plain files, until you find a way that fits your use-case best and that you feel comfortable with.

Comment: dbus is already running and has a perl module.

Comment: Does main-process start side-process?

Answer (score 1):

This question is very broad really - so much so that there's a whole document about how to ipc in perl - [`perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) - for sustained IO I would suggest considering a `pipe`, or actually possible looking at using `threads` and a shared memory model.